# Previewing large datasets in the front end of a web app (Angular)

Tags: angular, dataframe, pagination, bigdata, preview

I'm building an Angular 7 app where the user is able to upload big data-sets around 10.0000x10.0000 or even more. At some step after uploading the files, user should be able to make a preview of the the file he/she had uploaded.

So I was wondering if there is any specific way to do that without loading the whole data-set at once. What I thought is a datatable that will have a paginator for both columns and rows. Under this case, only a specific window of the original dataset will be displayed to the user (e.g 200x200) and he could navigate within it using the paginators.

I searched for horizontal/vertical paginator tables in google but couldn't find something useful. Do such elements have another name that I could search them by? Do you ever have seen something like this be implemented?

Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions for a library to 'preview'/'view' the data on a table-like structure?

Comment: Yes, but with the option for both column and row pagination. Or any other alternative way to implement something like that

Comment: I recommend Ag-grid!

Comment: I looked at it but couldn't find an example with row&column paginators

Comment: It has pagination for rows. But I am not sure what do you mean by column paginators. Can you show me an example? An image/mockup or something?

Comment: So here is a simple drawing https://imgur.com/NWQCL5U. The black rect. is the whole table while the red one is the window (e.g 100columnsx30rows) the user is able to see. From there, the user can click the down/up arrow to move a window downwards/upwards or click the right/left to move rightwards/leftwards in the original table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many "data grid" and "spreadsheet" components compatible with Angular you can try, such as [Ag-Grid](https://angular-grid.ag-grid.com/), [Syncfusion](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started/) and [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/). (Some are open-source/dual-licensed, others are commercial.)

However:

1. Typically these components only support row pagination, so you'll
   need to add column pagination, with an eye towards performance.
2. From a UX perspective, making the user inspect a 10k-by-10k data grid for correctness is not very friendly, even with scrollers and paging.

Instead you might want to consider alternatives.  Maybe just show the user subsets taken from the "four-corners" of the data table (e.g., several rows/columns from top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right of the table) -- plus show the user summary statistics (number of rows & columns read, etc.)

Here's a rough mockup of what could be shown to the user after an upload. (This preview can be quickly constructed from four fixed tables.)  Perhaps this might trigger some ideas:

[image: Mockup showing corner parts of a spreadsheet]

No scrolling / paging required and the user can verify the upload at a glance.